# How to read and manipulate Avro schema (avsc format)

Tags: python, avro, avsc

## I want to use the Avro schema and read it in python. Cannot read the schema. It is throwing an error

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("user.avsc","rb").read())
schema_1=schema.meta
print(schema_1)
```

Comment: What error? Please add more details

Comment: This is the error
AttributeError: 'RecordSchema' object has no attribute 'meta'

Comment: import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter




schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("fraud_alert.avsc","rb").read())

print(schema)
print(type(schema))
The type of the object returned is Avro.schema. Recordschema. I want to use this object but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read the fields in the schema (user.avsc) ? If so:
schema would be a list of all the fields in the avsc file
[each.name for each in schema] would give the list of fields.

Hope that helps...

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, which you will be able to make when you reach 50 reputation. Your contribution in attempting to answer the question is appreciated but please reserve the answer section for concrete solutions.